# unable to reset super user for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, installation

I have installed Postgres and during the installation changed the default super user name from postgres to "myuser". After the installation is complete I am unable to login using "myuser". I tried changing the conf file pg_hba.conf:

before change:

```
host  all all 127.0.0.1/32  md5
```

after change:

```
host  all all 127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

And I restarted the service after the change. However when I try to login in cmd:

```
psql -U myuser
```

I get following error:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  database "myuser" does not exist
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes read the error message `FATAL: database "myuser" does not exist` and ask yourself why it is saying that? Then read [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Comment: If the config stays as md5 then it complains about the password it doesn't say user doesn't exists. Besides I take screenshots as I do the installation.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a database that *does* exist?

Comment: Read the error it is complaining about the database not existing, not the user.

Comment: Again the initial error I am getting was __password authentication failed for user "my_user"__. I get __database "my_user" doesn't exist__ error only when I change the config file. I appreciate the sarcasm but it is not helping here

Comment: Also the postgres installation is part of another software I am trying to install. I am not doing a stand alone postgres installation. All the database, users were created as part of the installation

Comment: Try specifying the database. `psql -U myuser -d postgres`. (Or the appropriate install database name).

Comment: Thank you Belayer, I still get the password authentication failed error. This is why I was trying to reset the password using config file change.

Comment: I can answer your question if you tell me your operating system.

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the suggestion, I tried changing the config and I was able to login to the database. Now when I try to change the password using  ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD ***** I get role"myuser" does not exist. Getting close to fix this

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe windows server 2019

Comment: 1) The point was/is that error messages exist for a reason and reading what they say is an important part of troubleshooting. 2) There was no sarcasm involved, I was pointing out what the error message was telling you since you where not doing 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belayer's comment helped to resolve the issue. The error message saying database don't exist was misleeding in a way since I wasn't passing the database name.

After all I was able to login and change the password using below command:

ALTER USER myuser WITH PASSWORD *****

Make sure to pass the user name within ""

Thanks all for your inputs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).